# Are telecommute jobs really telecommute in careers section?

Tags: discussion, support, jobs

It seems that many of the jobs that are supposed to be telecommute (using the 'only telecommute jobs') aren't really looking for true remote employees.

To me, this leads to a lot of confusion because **if I am looking for a telecommute position, I don't want to relocate or work a few days from home I want a true telecommute position.**

If the job ad says relocation offered, and telecommute, and they want you to be living in the same city so you can attend weekly meetings etc, is that really a telecommute position?

I understand this is play on words, but for me (and I am sure others) we are interested in 100% work from home position, maybe there should be a new category 'remote only' or **we should be more strict on the 'only telecommute' to be...well...only telecommute.**

Answer (score 15):

Fully agreed. We see telecommute as "work from anywhere" and will contact an employer to clarify this if a listing is unclear, and edit the listing accordingly (that said, sometimes employers will be open to both, so having a job marked both as "telecommute" and "relocation offered" doesn't necessarily mean they won't allow pure telecommuting).

The best thing to do when you see a telecommute listing that looks like it might not actually be a true telecommute position is to flag it so we can check with the employer and edit it if necessary.

Comment: It seems to me that there are in fact two different kinds of 'telecommute,' but that isn't being reflected. _*Opportunity for Telecommute*_ means you will be able to work from home sometimes but we need you to be local to the office for meetings, etc.  _*Work from home*_ means if you can get there, and find an internet connection, you can work from the Moon for all we care.  Maybe it could be useful to allow employers to more clearly identify which camp the opportunity is in?